# How to merge changes into a branch from the parent's parent in git?

Tags: git

I have a branch coming from master and another branch coming from it.

```
master
   -- branch-a
      -- branch-b
```

Is it possible to pull changes from master into branch-b without them first being pulled into branch-a?

Comment: AFAIK branches don't have parents, only commits do. As branches are just labels, you should be able to merge anything into any branch and it won't affect the other branches.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, in GitHub (Mac) I only see an option to Update from Default Branch. Is there a command line switch to specify which branch to pull the update from?

Comment: Where do you see that option? While I suppose I know what you rmean, neither 'update' nor 'default branch' sounds like pure git. Do you use any graphical git client (sourcetree/tortoise/tower/etc?), or some website tool like GitHub/GitLab/Stash/Bitbucket/etc?

Answer (score 0):

when you are on branch-b -

```
git merge --no-ff master
```

Answer (score 0):

In git, branches just label specific commits. When you want to merge changes, you're trying to take all the commits on one branch and apply them to another branch.

In regards to your question, you can merge master directly into `branch-b` regardless of `branch-a`. On the command line, you would `git checkout branch-b` and then `git merge master`.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone stated earlier, branches are label specific commits. If you wish to add specific commits from different branches (master in this case), you can always do cherry-picking. 
eg.

```
$ git cherry-pick <commit-to-be-applied-from-master-to-branch-b>
```

This way, commits are only applied on branch b but not on branch a.